# Confusion in creating sub array from vector main array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iterator

So I was going through a posted code somewhere:

```
public:
    TreeNode* sortedArrayToBST(vector<int>& nums) {
      if(nums.size() == 0) return NULL;
     int mid=nums.size()/2;

       TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
    auto it=nums.begin()+1;
    cout<<*it;

     vector<int> left(nums.begin(),nums.begin()+mid);
     vector<int> right(nums.begin()+mid+1,nums.end());
     root->left=sortedArrayToBST(left);
     root->right=sortedArrayToBST(right);

     return root;
     }
```

let sample input be [1,2,3,4]

So as I print the iterator it,it gives me the answer as 3

Also, however while creating the sub array,the sub array is created consists of elements [1,2]. I get confused here,shouldn't the sub array be [1,2,3] as the nums.begin()+ middle would point at element 3? I think i have a very basic and naive doubt,could someone clear this 
Thanks

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but this code is a massive waste of runtime resource - it should use views onto the original vector instead of creating two new copies at each step

Answer (score 2):

C++ normally uses a system where the "begin" iterator points *at* the first item to be included in the result, but the "end" iterator points *one past* the last item to be included in the result.

Now there's one more minor problem: you *really* want to use something like a `vector_view` (aka `array_view`, aka `span`), that gives vector-like access to existing data, rather than copying it--as is, it'll be substantially slower than there's any real need for). If you don't have that available, you could either implement one of your own, or just pass a pointer/iterator and a length.

Answer (score 1):

The [`vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes two iterator arguments, `first` and `last`, copies all the elements in the range starting from `first` up to but not including `last`.

Think about the case when `vector<T>::begin()` and `vector<t>::end()` are passed to this constructor - `vector<t>::end()` refers to an element one past the end of the array, and cannot actually be dereferenced, so iterator ranges are generally specified as `[first, last)` (exclusive of `last`) rather than `[first, last]` (inclusive of `last`).